# prestashop 1.6 how to move logo to center and search bar to left

Tags: prestashop

I need to move logo to center and search bar to left. I've created a new tpl called logo.tpl. where do I need to include before HOOK_TOP? I need a controller file to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They way to go is to make a simple module, which uses `hookDisplayTop`.

Return the logo block using this function, and then got to `Modules > Positions` and swap the block positions around. You won't be able to insert a custom block into the `$HOOK_TOP` variable unless you use the hook (`displayTop`).

Another idea: why not just attach the logo markup to the search block ? Modify the `blocksearch-top.tpl` and remove the original block from the header. This probably event better.